# Geo Fence: how to find if a point or a shape is inside a polygon using oracle spatial

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, oracle-spatial

How do i find if a point or a polygon is inside another polygon using oracle spatial SQL query

Here is the scenario;

I have a table (STATE_TABLE) which contains a spatial type (sdo_geometry) which is a polygon (of say a State), I have another table (UNIVERSITY_TABLE) which contains spatial data (sdo_geometry) (point/polygon) which contains Universities;

Now how do i find if a selected University('s) are in a given State using SQL select statement.

Primarily i want to locate existence of given object(s) in a geofence.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to need to use either SDO_CONTAINS or SDO_RELATE with a mask of 'CONTAINS'

Please see documentation located at

SDO_CONTAINS
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_operat.htm#sthref1064 for

or

SDO_RELATE
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_operat.htm#i78531

Either one of these you'd do something like the following (assuming your spatial information is contained in a column called 'GEOM' that is spatially indexed):

```
select 
    ST.NAME, UT.UNIVERSITY_NAME
from
    STATE_TABLE ST
    INNER JOIN UNIVERSITY_TABLE UT
      ON SDO_CONTAINS(ST.GEOM, UT.GEOM) = 'TRUE'
```

You'll have to forgive me as I don't specifically remember the correct syntax for this and I don't know if the above join will work properly at all.  This should be enough to point you in the right direction though.

Comment: Dave! thanks for your response; it surely paved a direction in which i should work on solving the problem. It was taking me time implementing the same as i got into solving other problems. Will respond soon.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Happened to be up late last night and saw this.

Comment: Side note on this, the documentation was a bit vague (or at least my interpretation of it was) as to what this operation truly does but, suffice it to say, it looks like SDO_CONTAINS(A,B) should try to see if B is contained by A.  You might run into issues with border cases, such as, when the university geometry touches or exceeds the boundary of the state.  For that you might need to use the SDO_RELATE with different options in the filter or mask parameter.

Comment: Thanks Dave, your first solution works perfectly. I would try and look into the issue you have pointed out about the border cases. For now I have no proper data in my database with which I could replicate and solve the scenario. I would surely try to address it as well as I want the query to be robust.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! Been about 5 or so years since I did any GIS work and I miss it greatly! Again, glad to help.