# Point-in-polygon in spatial sql without cross join (oracle with sde)?

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial-query, point-in-polygon

I would like to do a point in polygon test using spatial SQL (DBMS Oracle with SDE for spatial tables). I have a spatial, materialized view containing points and I would like to add the polygon ID (from a different table) in which a point lies to this view.

I found `SDO_INSIDE(point, polygon)` and `SDO_RELATE(point, polygon, ‘INSIDE’)` which do the exact same thing. Both work, but a cross join seems to be necessary, which is very expensive regarding calculation time.

Here an example code of how I’m testing SDO_INSIDE by just using the materialized view as it is:

```
SELECT  MAT_VIEW.POINT_ID
       ,MAT_VIEW.SHAPE
       ,MAT_VIEW.POINT_COORD_E
       ,MAT_VIEW.POINT_COORD_N
       ,POLYGON_DATA.POLYGON_ID
FROM    MAT_VIEW
CROSS JOIN POLYGON_DATA
WHERE SDO_INSIDE(SDO_GEOMETRY(SDE.ST_ASTEXT(MAT_VIEW.SHAPE)),SDO_GEOMETRY(SDE.ST_ASTEXT(POLYGON_DATA.SHAPE))) = 'TRUE'
```

1. Is there a way to do this but without a cross join?
2. I also have the point coordinates as attributes. Is there a function that does not need the points, but just the coordinates instead?
   I only found SDO_POINTINPOLYGON, but this function seems not to work for my type of data (the coordinates need to be in SYS_REFCURSOR)?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601202/geo-fence-how-to-find-if-a-point-or-a-shape-is-inside-a-polygon-using-oracle-sp ? (I have no experience with spatial data, but thought your problem was interesting and looked to see what is available here, 150+ QA for `spatial oracle). Good luck.

Comment: I actually haven’t come along this question. Using an inner join instead of a cross join is a good idea, however, it does not speed up the query. And SDO_CONTAINS() is the exact opposite of SDO_INSIDE(), thus no gain in time either. But thanks anyway, I appreciate your help @shellter.